# Structpointer to array address

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures

Is it okay to give the address of a character array to a struct pointer ?

```
  typedef struct {
  int ID;
  word32 Myports;
  stripports gd[256] ;
  }Table;

  typedef struct {
  oldxmd used;
  newip  ip;
  newxmd new;
  }stripports;

  char buffer1[256];

  Table *tableptr = buffer1 ;

  tableptr ->ID = 15 ;
  tableptr ->Myports= somenumber ;
  tableptr ->gd[0].used = somenumber ;
```

The tough part is that I am not able to relate why the *tableptr* would accept  an array start address !
My best bet is that the above code is not correct or is unsafe .

Although casting was adopted later on but why does it accept an array  ?

```
 Table* tableptr = (Table*)buffer1;
```

`Table *tableptr = buffer1 ;` was replaced by `Table* tableptr = (Table*)buffer1;` in many tests that followed.

Without casting , Can a `struct` pointer take values other than the address of the  newly created pointee `struct` ?

I have a series of test written by many authors in the repository and its really confusing .

Comment: I believe it is safe, but trying to modify the buffer directly and then reading it back as a struct will yield undefined behvaior.

Comment: Nothing has been done to ensure that the buffer is correctly aligned to be used as a `Table`, so this code doesn't seem safe.

Comment: And `Table` is larger than buffer, so that seems dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning the address of a character array to a struct pointer is not guaranteed to work, there may be alignment issues.
Some architectures only allow `int`s to be aligned on even addresses while character arrays usually can start at any address.

There is also the buffer overrun issue. If the the `Table` type is bigger then the character array, you may end up overwriting other variables or getting a memory protection errors.

Both these issues can be overcome by changing

```
char buffer1[256];
```

to

```
char *buffer1 = (char*)malloc(sizeof Table);
```

Comment: Since this question is tagged "C", `#include <stdlib.h>` and ditch the cast to char*.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not ok.

The cast

```
Table* tableptr = (Table*)buffer1;
```

just tells the compiler to "Shut up and do it!". It doesn't magically make it work, it just makes the compiler not complain about it.